# gdalwarp batch process

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, batch, filter

I have downloaded numerous hdf files from an ftp site. Half of them were level 1 and the rest were level 2. Lvl1 format is Afile.A1_AC.sample.hdf and the lvl 2 format is: Afile.A1_AC.sample.hdf.

How will I do a batch process in projecting all the level2 files only?

How will I filter these files and create a new directory?

Here's what I have so far:

```
def inputData(self, event):

    def findSDS (path, filter):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
                yield file


     for sds in findSDS('/path/to/file', '*.hdf'):
        inSDS = 'HDF4_SDS:' + '/path/to/file' + '/' + sds + ':01'
        path = 'D:/new/dir' 
        outTIFF = path + sds + '.tif' 
        cmd = 'gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 %s %s' % (inSDS, outTIFF)

        os.system(cmd)
        os.mkdir(path)
```

---

(tried calling .bat from the python script and run the script. And it just created an empty/new directory(out_path). Tried calling the .bat from the cmd line and here's the output:

```
C:\sample>project.bat
C:\sample>set in_path=D:\path\to\file
C:\sample>set out_path=D:\newfolder
C:\sample>md D:\newfolder
A subdirectory or file D:\newfolder already exists.
C:\sample>cd D:\path\to\file
C:\sample>FORFILES /m *A1_AC*.hdf /C "cmd /c gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 @path D:\newfolder@fname.tif"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '+datum=WGS84 -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 @path D:\newfolder@fname.tif'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

---

```
C:\sample>project.bat
C:\sample>set in_path=D:\path\to\file
C:\sample>set out_path=D:\newfolder
C:\sample>md D:\newfolder
C:\sample>cd D:\path\to\file
C:\sample>FORFILES /m *A1_AC*.hdf /C "cmd /c gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 @path D:\newfolder@fname.tif"
ERROR: Files of type "*A1_AC*.hdf" not found.
```

---

```
C:\sample>projected.bat
C:\sample>set in_path=D:\path\to\file
C:\sample>set out_path=D:\newfolder
C:\sample>md D:\newfolder
C:\sample>cd /d D:\path\to\file
C:\sample>FORFILES /m *A1_AC*.hdf /C "cmd /c gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 @path D:\newfolder/@fname.tif"
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
'+proj=longlat
```

Tried running the gdalwarp in the cmd line and it was successful:

```
C:\sample>gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 HDF4_SDS:hdf:"Afile.A1_AC.sample.hdf":01 sample.tif
Creating output file that is 1941P x 1670L.
Processing input file HDF4_SDS:hdf:"Afile.A1_AC.sample.hdf":01.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution as windows batch script, maybe it'll help:

```
set in_path=path_to_stored_hdfs
set out_path=path_to_proccessed_ones

md %out_path%

cd /d %in_path%

FORFILES /m *L2_LAC*.hdf /C "cmd /c gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 HDF4_SDS:hdf:@file:01 %out_path%\@fname.tif"
```

Where `/m` is a mask to match desired filenames - for further details: http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Looking at your code I understand you've set *GDAL* path in system so gdalwarp should work.

Comment: Hi, tried your script but the equal sign from the set in part is having a syntax error. What should I do?

Comment: Hi, of course "in" is reserved for scrippting - sorry for my mistake (tried to write an answer as pseudocode first and forgot to change it later). I've made an edit in answer, now you shouldn't get a syntax error.

Comment: I think I'm maybe doing wrong. Using the script I posted I just replaced everything from insds until os.mkdi(path) with your script. I've made an update in the python script.

Comment: the in_path is now causing the syntax error. I'm being dumb at this.

Comment: As I wrote in answer: script I posted will do the work - but it's windows script - you can save it as a *.bat and run it in windows (as an alternative way to your python script). Your solution looks like it needs some improvements: first - you're creating output dir (same) in every iteration, what's more first you run a command (wchich is suposed to save some data in output dir) a then you finnally create the output dir. Try also printing inSDS outTIFF - if they're correctly passed to gdalwarp command.

Comment: Hi, I saved it as a .bat and I run it in my python script but it only created an empty folder which is the out_path? Another thing is what does /C and /c means? And this part of your script "@path %out_path%@fname.tif", does it saved the projected files with the same filename?

Comment: Added an update.

Comment: Try changing last line to: FORFILES /m *L2_LAC*.hdf /C "cmd /c gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs 'proj=longlat +datum=WGS84' -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 @path %out_path%/@fname.tif" - cmd doesn't cope with nested double quote. "@path" and "@fname" are FORFILES command variables - see the description I enclosed in my answer. Same with /C starts a cmd console /c - runs command.

Comment: Here is now the error after running the .bat file again>>> ERROR: Files of type "L2_LAC.hdf" not found.

Comment: Make sure you didn't miss asterisk "*" in /m mask - it's swiped out in comment cause it's text formatting variable here.

Comment: Adding an asterisk in /m mask doesn't correct the error. Maybe the in_path is missing in the cmd command. I'm just not sure, just correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The in_path must point to directory where you store .hdf files. The out_path is path to dir where the result should be written. Then the script will make directory as you set in out_path. Next step is to change active dirrectory to in_path to loop over all files defined in /m mask - for each matching the mask /C command will be executed. So edit the whole .bat and run it like you did before.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and now I don't know why I'm getting a file type not found error.

Comment: check update 2.

Comment: Well, you start a .bat in C:\User\Desktop\sample and next the command cd is trying to change active directory: ad /d after cd command to change drive = like `cd /d %in_path%` this should work. One more: in FORFILES command add "\" - in bat you ran it's missing between %out_path% and @fname = `%out_path%\@fname.tif`

Comment: This error appeared, see update 3. But I think I'm maybe getting near. I think the sds of the hdf file in the forfiles/cmd is missing. Because when I run gdalwarp in cmd line I indicated the sds which is the 01. But how will I indicate the sds to the FORFILES?

Comment: Where should I put the HDF4_SDS: and the 01?

Comment: Try exchanging `@path` with: `HDF4_SDS:hdf:@file:01` - @file is a variable of FORFILES which store filename and file extension. Also change the -t_srs part: double quotes in proj definition are messing with /c command which is also in double quotes = maybe try -t_srs EPSG:4326 - it should be latlon in WGS84.

Answer (score 1):

you can use batch hegtool, read this:

http://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGFAQ_CLI.html

and this:

http://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEG_Batch_job_Help.htm